# How to change the contents of a page on logging in?

Tags: css, authentication

I have a page which without logging in shows some details. What I have done so far is that after logging in, I point to another page which shows the same details plus more.

But now I want the code for both the pages to be in the same file. As in after logging in, I want to replace some elements on the same page.

(For logging in I am using Firebase)

For example (this is just an example to give an idea of how what I am trying to say), 
The page without logging in will show:

Welcome to Zest
Please Login to access other features

And after logging in, the same page will show:

Welcome to Zest
Name: Johnny

How do I go about doing this?
Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please share your code and the error you are facing.

Comment: @nish My code is for 2 different pages. I don't know how to do it in one page, which is why I am asking the question. I haven't coded anything for a single page.

Comment: This is tagged with "firebase", but I don't really see what this has to do with firebase.  It sounds like a DOM manipulation.

Comment: @Doug I just mentioned it as I am using that for logging in.